# Scraping tweets with rtweet: How to get geolocations (lookup_coords)?

Tags: r, twitter, geolocation, rtweet

I'm trying to extract tweets from Twitter and plot them into a map using rtweet. I copied some code from the internet. I have everything set up (including Twitter API and Google Maps API). The following code works just fine:

```
library(rtweet)
rt <- search_tweets("corona", include_rts=FALSE, "lang:en", geocode = lookup_coords("usa"), n = 10000, type="mixed")

# create lat/lng variables using all available tweet and profile geo-location data
rt <- lat_lng(rt)

# plot map
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
maps::map("world", regions="usa", lwd = .25)

# plot lat and lng points ontomap
with(rt, points(lng, lat, pch = 20, cex = .75, col = rgb(0, .3, .7, .75)))
```

However, as soon as I try to plot another country it doesn't work. For example, if I try to plot the same search term, but this time I want to have a map of the UK this doesn't work:

```
rt <- search_tweets("corona", include_rts=FALSE, "lang:en", geocode = lookup_coords("uk"), n = 10000, type="mixed")

# create lat/lng variables using all available tweet and profile geo-location data
rt <- lat_lng(rt)

# plot map
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
maps::map("world", regions="uk", lwd = .25)

# plot lat and lng points ontomap
with(rt, points(lng, lat, pch = 20, cex = .75, col = rgb(0, .3, .7, .75)))
```

The problem obviously is that

```
    rt <- search_tweets("corona", include_rts=FALSE, "lang:en", geocode = lookup_coords("uk"), n = 10000, type="mixed")
```

results in an empty data frame. The same happens with other countries. Does anybody have an idea why? Or does anybody know of another way doing this? Help would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot and trying different things I found the answer. It's really simple:

You need not only to register with Google Cloud Platform and set up an API. But you also need to enter your credit card information and set up the billing information. Then activate everything (Geocoding API, Places, etc). Then it works :)

Comment: how does Google Cloud Platform have anything to do with the Twitter API and R, though? Is this because you're using the Geocoding API to do the coordinate lookup?

Comment: I don't know :D But I use the geocoding API. It nevertheless unclear to me why it worked with the US data, but not with the other countries.